# Стиль ListView в приложении на фрагментах и AppCompatActivity

Tags: java, android, listview, expandablelistview, android-style

Сделал приложение, которое работает на `v4.Fragment`. Написал в `styles.xml` темную и светлую темы и устанавливаю их в главном `Activity`. Во всех фрагментах стили(оформление) работает хорошо, но в одном фрагменте, который вызывается из `Toolbar` стиль не назначается.

**Примечание**

В некоторых фрагментах, которые содержат `ExpandableListView` стили работают отменно, но в фрагменте из `Toolbar` (в нем просто `ListView`) нет.

В чем может быть причина ?

**UPD0**
*разметка экрана с `ExpandableListView*

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainLL"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/expLV"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="none" />

</FrameLayout>
```

*разметка экрана с простым`ListView*

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<View
    android:id="@+id/shadow_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/suggestion_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/shadow_view" />
```

P.S.: особых отличий нет. `View` во второй разметке - "аля" тень для `Toolbar`'а.

**UPD1**

// две цветовые схемы. Каждая из них заполнена максимально, но используется не вся.

```
 <style name="AppThemeLight" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" >
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/aa_primaryColor_lightTheme</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/aa_primaryDarkColor_lightTheme</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/aa_accentColor_lightTheme</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/aa_backgroundColor_lightTheme</item>
    <item name="android:colorForeground">@color/aa_foregroundColor_lightTheme</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/aa_primaryTextColor_lightTheme</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/aa_secondaryTextColor_lightTheme</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/aa_windowBackgroundColor_lightTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="AppThemeDark" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" >
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/ab_primaryColor_darkTheme</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/ab_primaryDarkColor_darkTheme</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/ab_accentColor_darkTheme</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/ab_backgroundColor_darkTheme</item>
    <item name="android:colorForeground">@color/ab_foregroundColor_darkTheme</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/ab_primaryTextColor_darkTheme</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/ab_secondaryTextColor_darkTheme</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/ab_windowBackgroundColor_darkTheme</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Ну... Может у вас там фон как-нибудь жестко прописан и перекрывает стиль?..

Comment: Пока что ничего определённого сказать не получается - не хватает информации. Особо не понятно что значит `фрагмент из Toolbar`

Comment: Тогда отличий быть не должно. Видать проблема в стилях. Добавьте их в вопрос.

Comment: И поясните что именно ожидается и что на деле выходит.

Comment: Всё ещё не ясно какие аттрибуты не сработали. И может у вас в разметке элементов списка что-то жестко задано.

Comment: Но в адаптерах-же какая-то разметка для элементов ведь используется...

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, в адаптерах android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1. А в LV просто android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1. Юрий, я предыдущие свои комментарии удалю, чтобы  оставить только полезное.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего дело в том, что взятая вами [системная](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/simple_list_item_1.xml) разметка для элемента списка имеет своё представление о цвете текста, перекрывающее переопределённые вами глобальные аттрибуты типа `textPrimaryColor`. В качестве обходного решения можно передать адаптеру собственную разметку элемента, указав ей тот же `id`, что и у системной:

```
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimary"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"/>
```

Если вышележащий файл назвать `my_list_view_item.xml`, то создание адаптера будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,
    R.layout.my_list_view_item, someStringArrayThatMustNotBeNull);
```

Правильным же решением, на мой взгляд, будет полный отказ как от `ListView` так и от системных для него адаптеров и разметок. Ибо над ними нет полного контроля как в, например, вашем случае.

Comment: Классно придумали! Гениально, если быть кратким. Сейчас опробую на деле.

Comment: Если в TextView оставить Ваш вариант цвета текста "android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimary" ", то ничего не меняется. Что до изменений разметки , что после. Но, если " в лоб" задать цвет из палитры цветов "@color/bla-bla", то все работает отменно. Я в замешательстве. Почему так ?

Comment: @web_alex, ну... А если вот так: `android:textColor="?textColorPrimary"`?

Comment: ?textColorPrimary подчеркнуто красным. Есть только "?attr/colorPrimary", но приложение крашится в этом случае с ошибкой android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>

Comment: @web_alex, ну, попробуйте тогда в `res/values` создать файл `attrs.xml`, создать в нём свой аттрибут `<attr name="myTextColor" format="color|reference"/>`, в обеих темах назначить ему цвет `<item name="myTextColor">@color/ТУТ_ЦВЕТ_ДЛЯ_ОПРЕДЕЛЁННОЙ_ТЕМЫ</item>` и назначать `android:textColor="?myTextColor"`

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                      android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>

Comment: @web_alex, а если `android:textColor` убрать то не падает?..

Comment: Не падает, но и текст старой окраски тогда.

Comment: Так... А тестируете на каком апи? Ну а так, видать, придётся вам жестко задавать цвет через `@color/bla-bla`, создавать по разметке на каждую тему и программно определяя какая у вас тема назначать нужную разметку при создании адаптера. А потом попробовать таки свой адаптер со своей разметкой и удивиться тому, что так проблем не будет никаких)

Comment: API16. Да, сделаю через @color/bla-bla. Подберу подходящий и норм)))